# rails select form array error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `.select` to assign a "line_id" to an "instance". The class "Instance" `belongs_to` "Line".

```
<%= line_builder.select('instance', 'line.line_id', Line.all.collect {|p| [p.title, p.id ]}, { :include_blank => 'select line' }) %>
```

this line returns this error:

```
undefined method `merge' for #<Array:0x007fc3c389e868>
```

Not quite sure whats going wrong here, but i'm assuming it's the syntax of the `.select` method because i've never used it before.

What else can I show you to help me figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select):

```
<%= line_builder.select(:line_id, Line.all.collect {|p| [p.title, p.id ]}, { :include_blank => 'select line' }) %>
```

## Reason it was not working:

> You had an extra argument in your select: A select in a Form builder takes as arguments the method to call for update (here `line_id`, so Rails will call `line_id` of the object and assign it the value of the select box), second argument is the options for the select, third option is the `html_options` as a `Hash`. As you had an extra argument, Rails was expecting your options to be the `html_options` hash, which was your options of the select.

Comment: undefined method `merge' for #<ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer:0x007fc3c3c02630>on second line.

Comment: that second one seems to have done it... any chance you can explain to me why?

Comment: You had an extra argument in your `select`: A select in a Form builder takes as arguments the method to call for update (here line_id, so Rails will call line_id of the object and assign it the value of the select box), second argument is the options for the select, third option is the html_options as a Hash. As you had an extra argument, Rails was expecting your options to be the html_options hash, which was your options of the select. (hope It makes sense ...)

Comment: yes, that makes perfect sense, I feel a little misled by apidock.com which shows an additional "object" argument "select(object, method, choices, options = {}, html_options = {}) public"

Comment: Yes its confusing but here you are using a form_builder, which already knows the 'object' for the form.